# Bootstrap pagination with dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I need to be able to paginate a table in my bootstrap modal.

The problem I'm having is that I build the table rows dynamically.

**The code which builds up the table rows.**

```
function getValidTags(){
  var ruleID = $('.ruleID').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/getValidTags.php',
    type: 'POST',          
    data: {
      ruleID: ruleID,
    },
  })
  .done(function(data) {    
    $.each(data, function(validName, afCount) {
        var newValidRow = '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+validName+'</td><td>'+afCount+' Autofixes</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>'+
        '</tr>'; 
        $('.validTagsTable').append(newValidRow);        
    });
  })
}
```

How do I add pagination to my table? I would like to be able to limit one page to 20 table rows?

**Here's my HTML**

```
           <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tag Name</th>
                    <th>Autofixes</th>
                    <th>Manage</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="validTagsTable">
            </tbody>                    
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <nav>
              <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>                      
        </div>
```

Comment: You can make your life easier by using the dataTables plugin. The answer below provides you the link.. Don't hesitate to use it.. You will love it

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot use a framework that does this for you? [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) does all of this for you.

Comment: I've never used this, does it take a while to get used to?

Comment: No not at all. It's one of the most popular libraries our there but there are alternatives. They have a zero configuration option where one line of code gives you the most common functionality. Everything can be overridden to match your requirements if needed though. It will certainly take you less time to configure than it will to manually implement pagination!

Comment: How do i implement it into my ajax? I have the stylesheet and script but I can't get it to work? `$('.valid-tags').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "tag_name" },
            { "data": "af_count" }
        ]
    } );`

Comment: The documentation is excellent and you'll not have any problems finding answers here on S.O. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html